# Is it possible to invoke an instance of a class whose name is passed as a variable?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing in Laravel 9, though I assume this is Php-specific. Example below of what I'm trying to achieve: Imagine I have a controller named `HomeController.php` with a `getData()` method that returns something I need...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController
{
    public function getData()
    {
        return [my data]
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to call that class and method in a dynamic way, and assign my data to `$data`...

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

class Example
{
    public $className = 'HomeController';
    public $method = 'getData';

    public function index()
    {
        $instance = new $this->className;
        $method = $this->method;

        $data = $instance->$method();
    }
    
}
```

I have a variation of this setup in my application, and it's not working. I get the following error: `Class "HomeController" not found`.

If I replace `$this->className` with `HomeController` it works. Keep in mind `$className` will be passed from elsewhere, I want to avoid hard-coding class names into my `Example` class.

It is true that I will still need to include them all at the top anyway, but I just want to know if it's possible to pass a class name like that. Unless there's a way to dynamically include those too, but I doubt it.

**Edit**: Tim's answer in the comments worked great. Here is a fixed version:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

class Example
{
    public $className = 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController'; // Change 1
    public $method = 'getData';

    public function index()
    {
        $instance = app()->make($this->className); // Change 2
        $method = $this->method;

        $data = $instance->$method();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to use the FQCN (Fully Qualified ClassName), so `public $className = 'App\\Http\\Controller\\HomeController';` instead of just `public $className = 'HomeController';`. Also, instead of `new $this->className`, use `$instance = app()->make($this->className)`, then `$instance->{$thismethod}()` (as a one-liner, or your approach on that end is fine)

Comment: An alternative is a `Trait` in PHP, like `class DataTrait { public function getData(){ ... }}`, then you can `use` this trait on both your `HomeController` and `Example` classes. More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: I'm working with `$className = 'App\\Http\\Controller\\HomeController';`, and `$instance = app()->make($className);` now, and getting a different error: `Target class [App\Http\Controller\HomeController] does not exist.` Any ideas? I have not tried the trait yet.

Comment: Woops... That should be `Controllers`, not `Controller`; my bad!

Comment: Oops! That's what I get for mindlessly copy and pasting. This works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: This is probably not as relevant in this specific case (since you're using Laravel and should use the container), but in general, you can use [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php), and do something like this: `$data = call_user_func([$this->className, $this->methodName]);`.

Comment: _Side note:_ If you need to call a method in one controller from another, you should rethink the design. If you have some method you need to call from different places, it should probably be moved into some service, to some parent controller you extend from or, as mentioned, a trait.

Comment: Haha all good; my fault for typing it out instead of copying/pasting  Also, M. Eriksson's suggestions are also very good; basically there's lots of ways to call a function from another class, or reuse code, etc.; look into some of the alternatives and see what works best for your use case. Cheers!

Comment: And lastly, I'd move that edit to an actual Answer below; posting the solution in the Question is generally not the approach on Stackoverflow 

Comment: @TimLewis - Just "pretty" good? ;-)

Comment: @M.Eriksson Haha ok fine, "very good" 

Comment: I actually found another way in [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container#method-invocation-and-injection). You should be able to do: `$data = $app->call([$this->className, $this->method]);`. Seems like it works similar to `call_user_func()` but it will use the container to resolve the dependencies as well. It's worth reading up on the container, it's very powerful (I use it in almost all my applications, even though I'm not using Laravel)

Comment: @TimLewis you can do it more cleanly: `public $className = HomeController::class;`

Comment: @RoboRobok Yes, of course; `HomeController::class` will also return the FQCN, assuming `use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;` is at the top of the file (which it is in this case)  It was also said this is coming from somewhere else, so something like `new Example(self::class)` could work as well, etc. (with a proper `__construct()` method). Lots of different approaches. Cheers!

Comment: @TimLewis yup, the `use` is there.

Comment: @RgFirefly don't do that, you are not follownig standards and you are going to just have a mess of a code...